# Accumulated field based on ORDER field instead of first appearance

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I currently have this `events` table:

```
id | user | country | when
---+------+---------+-----------------------
5  | 1    | my      | "2011-07-21 00:00:00"
19 | 1    | my      | "2014-04-02 18:00:00"
20 | 1    | my      | "2014-04-09 18:00:00"
29 | 1    | my      | "2011-09-27 15:00:00"
30 | 1    | my      | "2011-02-01 15:00:00"
31 | 1    | my      | "2012-05-12 19:00:00"
75 | 1    | my      | "2014-06-20 16:00:00"
```

In the output I need to get the number of times a `user` has a `country` occurrence as well as an `accumulated`. For that, I use this query:

```
SELECT f.id, f.user, f.country, f.`when`, (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events AS f2
  WHERE f2.country = f.country AND f2.user = f.user
) AS countrytimes, (
  SELECT count(*) FROM events AS f3
  WHERE f3.country = f.country AND f3.id <= f.id AND f3.user = f.user
  ORDER BY f.`when` DESC
) AS accumulated
FROM events AS f
WHERE f.user = 1
AND f.country = 'my'
ORDER BY f.`when` DESC
```

The output of that query is based on field `when`, fine until here. The problem is that field accumulated is based on first appearances of the requested `user` and `country` instead of in the `when` field as well.

```
id | user | country | when                  | countrytimes | accumulated
---+------+---------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------
75 | 1    | my      | "2014-06-20 16:00:00" | 7            | 7
20 | 1    | my      | "2014-04-09 18:00:00" | 7            | 3
19 | 1    | my      | "2014-04-02 18:00:00" | 7            | 2
31 | 1    | my      | "2012-05-12 19:00:00" | 7            | 6
29 | 1    | my      | "2011-09-27 15:00:00" | 7            | 4
5  | 1    | my      | "2011-07-21 00:00:00" | 7            | 1
30 | 1    | my      | "2011-02-01 15:00:00" | 7            | 5
```

Table and query are in this **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e99b/2)**.

**How can I get it sorted so that the row with `when` = Feb 1st 2011 gets `accumulated` = 1?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll just have to change the accumulation criteria from `f3.id <= f.id` to `f3.when <= f.when` to get the accumulation by date instead of id;

```
SELECT f.id, f.user, f.country, f.when, (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events AS f2
  WHERE f2.country = f.country AND f2.user = f.user
) AS countrytimes, (
  SELECT count(*) FROM events AS f3
  WHERE f3.country = f.country AND f3.when <= f.when AND f3.user = f.user
  ORDER BY f.`when` DESC
) AS accumulated
FROM events AS f
WHERE f.user = 1
AND f.country = 'my'
ORDER BY f.`when` DESC
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e99b/5).

Comment: Dammit, I don't know how I missed that... Thanks!